# Calculate third column based on two other columns on creation of table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

So I want to create a table for library as follows:

Item

```
ID Name StartDate ReturnDate Fee
-- ---- --------- ---------- ---
5  Book 5-5-2016   7-5-2016   2
-- ---- --------- ---------- ---
```

So the above means there's a Book with ID 5 borrowed from 5th May to 7th May.
The fee column should automatically calculate and insert every time a new row is added, with $1 fee for each day between the dates.

How do you do this?
As in, how do you make SQL do this calculation on creation of tuple when the rest of data is inserted (Fee should be updated automatically)?

Comment: Is it MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Use triggers. (Or, even better, have a view instead.)

Comment: Jarlh is right. A trigger is what you are asking for, but a view would probably be better.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Oracle. SQL queries yeah? So it's MySQL too, right?

Comment: Oracle and MYSQL are quite different, so no Oracle is not MYSQL

Comment: Have you tried anything, or is this a do it for me question

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know how to create the table without this function (the calculate function) and I've done it too. Just don't know how to do the calculate bit. It's not a do it for me question.

Comment: [Triggers in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#LNPLS020). Try to build your own, then feel free to post a question if you have a specific issue with your trigger. Another approach, as said, could be leaving your table unmodified and building a [view](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504) to get your data and the evaluation of the fee as if it was all stored in a table

Comment: This doesn't sound like something you'd 'store' at all.

Comment: So the calcualted fee (`return_date - start_date`) is a default you want to store on insert and it can be changed later to a different value? But what if someone inserts a value, say `start_date =2016-05-05` / `return_date = 2016-05-07` / `fee = 4`? Don't you want the default to apply only when it's not specified in the insert statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you date column have date type

In Mysql  you can use date_diff

```
SELECT ID, Name, StartDate, ReturnDate, DATEDIFF(ReturnDate,StartDate) AS Fee
from your_table
```

for oracle simply subtract the date

```
SELECT ID, Name, StartDate, ReturnDate, 
ReturnDate - StartDate  Fee
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to create the table first and then update the fee column

the DDL should be

```
create table library (id bigint not null, name varchar(100),startDate date, returnDate date, fee int);
```

The update sql is

```
update library set fee=DATEDIFF(ReturnDate,StartDate);
```